# No mostrar determinados Id de producto

Tags: mysql

estoy haciendo un select que me llena un grid y todo bien, pero quiero que **no** me traiga los productos con `id 9998 y 9999` todo lo demas si, pero no se como integralo en mi query, me podria ayudar, ante mano gracias

```
SELECT u.id, u.nombre as nombre, u.apellidos as apellido, u.roleId, p.price as precio,o.quantity as cantidad, r.name as rol, o.productName as productos, sum(o.quantity*o.price) as venta, count(distinct b.id) as cuentas 
FROM bills b join usersoperacion u on(u.id=b.userIdAbrio and u.restId=b.restId) left join roles r on(r.id=u.roleId) join orders o on(o.restId=b.restId and o.billId=b.id) join products p on (o.restId=p.restId and o.productId=p.id) left join categories c on(p.categoryId=c.id and p.restId=c.restId) left join supercategories s on(c.superCategoryId=s.id and s.restId=c.restId) 
WHERE b.statusId=2 and o.createTime between '$fechaInicio' and '$fechaFinal' and b.restId=$restId and o.statusId!=4 $s $c $p 
GROUP BY u.id, o.productName 
ORDER BY o.productName, venta desc
```

Comment: proba con `and p.id not in (9998, 9999)` en el where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba agregarle como una clausula del `where` el codigo:

```
where u.id!=9998 and u.id!=9999
```

Espero te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

luego de hacer los joins puedes aplicar la clausula where para excluir los datos que no necesitas:

```
SELECT u.id, u.nombre as nombre, u.apellidos as apellido, u.roleId, p.price as precio,o.quantity as cantidad, r.name as rol, o.productName as productos, sum(o.quantity*o.price) as venta, count(distinct b.id) as cuentas 
FROM bills b join usersoperacion u on(u.id=b.userIdAbrio and u.restId=b.restId) left join roles r on(r.id=u.roleId) join orders o on(o.restId=b.restId and o.billId=b.id) join products p on (o.restId=p.restId and o.productId=p.id) left join categories c on(p.categoryId=c.id and p.restId=c.restId) left join supercategories s on(c.superCategoryId=s.id and s.restId=c.restId) 
WHERE p.id !=9998 and p.id!=9999 and b.statusId=2 and o.createTime between'$fechaInicio' and '$fechaFinal' and b.restId=$restId and o.statusId!=4 $s $c $p 
GROUP BY u.id, o.productName 
ORDER BY o.productName, venta desc
```